# tikzmark and issue with pgfsys-dvips.def

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvips, tikzmark, bakoma

When I try to use `\tikzmark` (actually, any feature that relies on the `[remember picture]` functionality of TikZ) in the WYSIWYG editor BaKoMa TeX, I get the following warning:

> Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support marking the current position. This warning is given only once on input line 24.

and the desired output is not rendered.

According to the developer of BaKoMa, this is an issue with the dvips driver of the PGF package, and not with BaKoMa editor.

Is this truly a bug of the PGF package? If so, is there a work-around before an official patch is available?

---

An example to illustrate how the problem looks like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {};
something

\bigskip

\centering

\tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node (c) [circle,draw] {Big circle};
  \draw [overlay,->,very thick,red,opacity=.5]
    (c) to[bend left] (n1) (n1) |- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Output via BaKoMa**
[image]

**Output via TeXworks** (with `pdflatex`)
[image]

Comment: Your example works for me using latex-dvips-ps2pdf so there is no problem with a current pgf system using dvips. Texlive 2013 has `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.de
File: pgfsys-dvips.def 2008/04/03  (rcs-revision 1.20)` which version is shown in your log?

Comment: I get the same as David Carlisle using the CVS version of PGF, so this looks like the version of PGF that you have is old.  Can you update it?

Comment: Note that your `latex` command must be `pdflatex running in dvi mode` as the whole feature relies on the `\pdflastxpos` feature. If you are using a classic TeX engine it can not work (but don't do that)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: BaKoMa maintains its own LaTeX distribution, and I use MikTeX with TeXworks. In both distributions, however, the `pgfsys-dvips.def` has the same version as yours, `v 1.20 2008/04/03 17:04:45`. When I compile in command line using `latex mwe.tex` twice, I get the desired result in `mwe.dvi`. But I still get the wrong output with BaKoMa...

Comment: @KevinC well that's probably it then, if bakoma does not implement the pdftex primitives then tikzmark can not work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is `pdftex` necessary to implement `remember picture`? Apparently `pdftex` is incompatible with the WYSIWYG feature of BaKoMa.

Comment: You need at least pdftex in dvi mode as it requires a primitive to save position which is not available in tex or etex but is in pdftex or luatex or xetex. All modern systems use pdftex for latex as well as pdflatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the explanation :) I'll see if BaKoMa tech support has any solution for this then...

Comment: @KevinC any update? Did BaKoMa support have any recommendations?

Comment: @PaulGessler: No, unfortunately... See http://bakoma-tex.com/menu/talk-messages.php?topic=20130905065707.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BaKoMa TeX 10.60 (published 14 Nov 2014) supports this feature.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: The assumption is that [the introduction of `\pdfsavepos`](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/changes.php?Ver=10.60#V1060) makes the difference?

Comment: Yes. adding \pdfsavepos and editing pgfsys-dvips.def solves the problem.

Comment: Screenshot http://www.bakoma-tex.com/screenshots/test-scr.png